# Varying the width of a image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

This web page has three buttons(red,blue,green).Three images are aligned horizontally.When a button is pressed the corresponding color image should be placed in the centre with width of 400 px(in start the width of each image is 200px).Whenever either red or green button is pressed the image in placed on top of the image present in the centre.Could someone provide a solution

```
<html>
<header>
<style>

#red {
width: 200px;
height:300px;
position:absolute;
left:10px;
}
#blue{
width: 200px;
height:300px;
position:absolute;
left:500px;
}
#green
{
width: 200px;
height:300px;
position:absolute;
right:100px;
}

</style>
</header>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Red" id="redButton"></input>
<input type="button" value="Blue" id="blueButton"></input>
<input type="button" value="Green" id="greenButton"></input>
<div id="images">
<img id="red" src="red.jpeg" alt="red" />
<img  id="blue" src="blue.jpeg" alt="blue" />
<img id="green" src="green.jpeg" alt="green"  />
</div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$('#redButton').bind('click', function( event1 )
{

$("#red").css({'width':'400px','position':'absolute','left':'400px', 'height':'300px'});
$("#blue").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','right':'50 px','height':'300px'});
$("#green").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','left':'50 px','height':'300px'});
console.log("Red button clicked");
});

$('#greenButton').bind('click', function( event2 )
{

$("#blue").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','right':'50 px', 'height':'300px'});
$("#green").css({'width':'400px','position':'absolute','left':'400px','height':'300px'});
$("#red").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','left':'50 px','height':'300px'});
console.log("Green button clicked");

});

$('#blueButton').bind('click', function( event3 )
{

$("#blue").css({'width':'400px','position':'absolute','left':'400px','height':'300px'});
$("#red").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','left':'50 px','height':'300px' });
$("#green").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','right':'50 px','height':'300px'});
console.log("Blue button clicked");
});

</script>
</html>
```

when the page is loaded:
[image]

when blue button is clicked:
[image]

when red button is clicked:
[image]

Comment: what does not work...

Comment: sorry but i am not getting what u want when u click red/green button..  clicking blue button will increase the blue image size thats ok.. but when i click red/green then what exactly u want.. ??

Comment: When the red button is pressed.The green image should be shifted to left('left':'50 px'),the blue image should be shifted to right('right':'50 px')and the red image should be in the center with double width.as u can see they are merged here.

Comment: @SameerSarmah if you want shift the blue image to left (to previous red image position) add ('left':'10px') see anwser below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altogether the listener code would be:

```
 <script>
    $('#redButton').bind('click', function( event1 )
    {

    $("#red").css({'width':'400px','position':'absolute','left':'400px', 'height':'300px'});
    $("#blue").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','left':'10px','right':'1000px','height':'300px'});
    $("#green").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','right':'10px','left':'1000px','height':'300px'});
    console.log("Red button clicked");
    });

    $('#greenButton').bind('click', function( event2 )
    {

    $("#blue").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','right':'10px','left':'1000px', 'height':'300px'});
    $("#green").css({'width':'400px','position':'absolute','left':'400px','height':'300px'});
    $("#red").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','left':'10px','right':'1000px','height':'300px'});
    console.log("Green button clicked");

    });

    $('#blueButton').bind('click', function( event3 )
    {

    $("#blue").css({'width':'400px','position':'absolute','left':'400px','height':'300px'});
    $("#red").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','left':'10px','right':'1000px','height':'300px' });
    $("#green").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','right':'10px','left':'1000px','height':'300px'});
    console.log("Blue button clicked");
    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED:**
This was the answer for your earlier question.
You should add `'left':'10px'` . (If you want to shift the blue image which is in the center to left on **clicking red button**)

```
$('#redButton').bind('click', function( event1 )
{

$("#red").css({'width':'400px','position':'absolute','left':'400px', 'height':'300px'});
$("#blue").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','right':'50 px','left':'10px','height':'300px'});
$("#green").css({'width':'200px','position':'absolute','left':'50 px','height':'300px'});
console.log("Red button clicked");
});
```

Comment: I want the blue image to be shifted right(where green was placed earlier), green to left(where red was placed earlier) and  the red image should be in the center with double width.